# Делаю простой калькулятор на c++ с помощью if и выдает ошибку

Tags: c++, if

Вот мой код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    char doing;
    double a,b,summ;
    cout << "Vvedite а: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Vvedite b: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Vvedite deistvie * ili + ili - ili : ";
    cin >> doing;
    if (doing == *) {
       summ == a * b;
    }  if (doing == :: ){
       summ == a : b;
    }  if (doing == + ){
       summ == a + b;
    }  if  (doing == -){
       summ == a - b;
    }
    
    cout << "summa = " << summ << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

А вот ошибки

> 14    19  C:\Users\Админ\Desktop\main.cpp [Error] expected
> primary-expression before ')' token
> 16    24  C:\Users\Админ\Desktop\main.cpp [Error] expected id-expression
> before ')' token 17   18  C:\Users\Админ\Desktop\main.cpp [Error] found
> ':' in nested-name-specifier, expected '::'
> 17    16  C:\Users\Админ\Desktop\main.cpp [Error] 'a' is not a class or
> namespace 18  23  C:\Users\Админ\Desktop\main.cpp [Error] expected
> primary-expression before ')' token
> 20    23  C:\Users\Админ\Desktop\main.cpp [Error] expected
> primary-expression before ')' token

Comment: Выражения после `doing ==` должны быть в кавычках

Comment: в данном случае напрашивается не куча if, а if - else if - else if и т.д. А еще лучше switch.

Comment: не забудьте поставить галочку, если считаете что мы вам помогли

Answer (score 2):

```
if (doing == '*') {
   summ = a * b;
}  if (doing == ':' ){
   summ = a / b;
}  if (doing == '+' ){
   summ = a + b;
}  if  (doing == '-'){
   summ = a - b;
}
```

Вы забили везде установить ' '

Answer (score 0):

```
if (doing == '*') {
   summ = a * b;
}  else if (doing == ':' ){
   summ = a / b;
}  else if (doing == '+' ){
   summ = a + b;
}  else if  (doing == '-'){
   summ = a - b;
}
```

Что вы сравниваете? Операторы? Кавычки нужно, т.к это символ. Для производительности кода пишите `else`.

Деление вот так: `/`.

```
summ == a - b;
```

Это не присвоение! Это сравнение! Замените на один равно везде, кроме где `if`

А еще оптимальней было бы через

```
switch(doing)
{
case '*' :
   summ = a*b;
case ':' :
   summ = a/b;
case '+' :
   summ = a+b;
case '-' :
   summ = a-b;
default:
   cout << "wrong!" << endl;
}
```